# Find longest squential streak in arraylist java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to write a code in java where suppose i have an arraylist of (1,3,4,5,8,9,11,12,13,14,15)

i need the code to analyze the longest streak of consecutive numbers in the arraylist. From the above arraylist 11,12,13,14,15 is the longest streak so the code should give this in the output in form of another arraylist.

the code should be executed on any ArrayList consisting of different numbers

actually, i have made the code where i have come up to the point of extracting index of postive values from a bigger arraylist and stored it in another arraylist. Now, im stuck at finding the longest streak of consecutive numbers in the newly made arraylist.

Here is my code:

```java
List<Integer> mega = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i <= data.size() - 1; i++) {
    double a = (data.get(i).adjClose) - (data.get(i).open); //calculating a value
    if (a > 0) { // if value is bigger than zero, then store the index of that element in a new arraylist
        mega.add(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: share the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Edit your question, and post the formatted code, please. See [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Are you working with integer or decimal values? Why are you accessing different attributes of the same object, what has this got to do with sequential values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ArrayList<Integer> bigger = new ArrayList<>();
for (int x = 0; x < numbers.size(); x++) {
  int current = numbers.get(x);
  ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
  temp.add(current);
  for (int y = x + 1; y < numbers.size(); y++) {
    int nextValue = numbers.get(y);
    if (nextValue == current + 1) {
      temp.add(nextValue);
      current = nextValue;
    }
    else {
      break;
    }
  }

  if (temp.size() > bigger.size()) {
    bigger.clear();
    bigger.addAll(temp);
  }
}
```

`numbers` is the ArraList of your numbers and 
Inside `bigger` is your sequence.